# How can I emulate Haskell's typeclasses in Scala?

Tags: scala, haskell, types, typeclass

Is there a way to define something like a typeclass (probably a trait?), and then later define an instance of that typeclass for a specific type, without modifying the original type definition?

For example, having the following code

```
class User {
}

trait Printable {
  def print(): String
}
```

Can I somehow make the `User` class `Printable` separately from the class definition, without having to say `class User extends Printable`?

Comment: Yes. There's something called the typeclass pattern. The behavior isn't exactly equivalent - there may be multiple implementations, and you have to bring the implementations into scope to make it work - but on principle, yes that exists.

Comment: @Cubic Could you show how in a an answer?

Comment: [Type Classes as Objects and Implicits](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/150280/files/TypeClasses.pdf) is a great paper on the implementation of type classes in Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a trait for the typeclass you want to define e.g.

```
trait Printable[T] {
   def print(p: T): String
}
```

then you can define implicit instances of this trait for the types you want:

```
object Instances {
    implicit val UserPrintable = new Printable[User] {
        def print(u: User) = u.name
    }
}
```

in any functions that require the typeclass you can add an implicit parameter for the instance:

```
def writePrintable[T](p: T)(implicit pclass: Printable[T]) {
    println(pclass.print(p))
}
```

then you can call `writePrintable` by importing the instance implementation e.g.

```
import Instances._
writePrintable(new User("user name"))
```

Comment: Note that you can define implicit instances in the companion object  of the new type (e.g. `Printable`) and in this case there is no need to import them explicitly.

Comment: There are also good reasons to avoid orphan instances whenever you can, just as in Haskell.